# Get data from all app's notification in IOS

Tags: swift, flutter, icloud

I would like to develop an IOS app to get notification such as title and body from all applications in iPhone. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: No, your all only has access to your apps stuff.

Comment: How about extract backup data from iCloud, Is it possible?

Comment: If there is some obscure way of doing it you wouldn’t find that information out here.

Comment: Yes that's right. I have searched about it around 2 weeks ago and I have not get any clues yet. I think maybe because of Apple privacy.

Comment: Or because it would be worth a lot of money. Why give it out for free.

Comment: And how about backdoor website, Do you know any websites which they can talk about this?

Comment: It isn’t about weather you can talk about it or not. If there is an app that is doing it as you mention below it would cost a small fortune to find out how. I’m sure you could go on a freelancer website offer a hefty sum and someone would figure it out. I believe programming is 90% creativity. You can only google so much.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. On Android, yes this is possible. But not on Apple. They restrict permissions so that you cannot access that information as a developer.

Comment: The purpose that I want is just wanna get message or conversion from Messages, Messenger, Telegram, ... so, In case I have iCloud credential Can I extract backup data from iCloud?

Answer (score 0):

Every application is given a sandbox, a directory it can use to store data in. If the application needs access to data on the device that isn't located in the application's sandbox, it needs to request the data through a system interface.
App can only read their notifications, other things are possible with Jailbreak.

Learn about app sandbox [here](https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-application-sandboxing/)

Comment: How about extract backup data from iCloud which provided iCloud credential Do you think it is possible?

Comment: No @BrosnaChhean

Comment: My boss saw [mSpy](https://www.guru99.com/enter-a-cell-phone-number-and-read-someones-texts-for-free.html) can do that. That's why he wanted me to research about it too but, I've not had any clues yet.